# How to create an image map with dynamic links from a static SVG file using Firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, svg, google-cloud-firestore

I have an .svg file which contains hundreds of `<path>` tags with unique ID's. I have a Firebase Firestore collection with the following fields: ID, NAME, URL. I need to dynamically make a link for each path from Firestore based upon the ID(which is the NAME field in Firestore) of the path.

How do I extract the IDs from the paths, look them up in Firebase, then make links using to the corresponding URL?

I want to dynamically create an image map from the .svg file based upon each path ID. I've tried to use jquery .wrap but wasn't able to produce any results.

I need to dynamically turn these static paths into links:

```
<path id="apple" d="M291.64266,2274.01282l-.00531.03405c-...">
<path id="banana" d="M496.18315-.08371.37079-...">
```

I need to look up "apple" & "banana" in my Firestore Collection, grab the URL, then turn the path into a link to get something like:

```
<a href="http://mylink.com/someapplelink"><path id="apple" d="M291.64266,2274.01282l-.00531.03405c-..."></a>

<a href="http://mylink.com/somebananalink"><path id="banana" d="M496.18315-.08371.37079-..."></a>
```

Perhaps there's a better way than wrapping it in `<a>` tags, perhaps just create onclick events?

Comment: You could get all the `path` with a jquery selector which would produce an array of all the paths, then loop over all those paths, get the id (`.attr('id')`), search , grab the url and then return something like this: `<a href="yourlink.com/idlink"> <pathelement on wich the loop is now/> </a>`

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm just not sure how to retrieve the data from Firestore and search/filter it based on the path id array and kick it back to the DOM

Comment: Then this question is going to be closed as **Too Broad**, you need to show what you have tried so far.